# Deploy Ruby on Rails Application running on linux platform to Microsoft Azure Platform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure

I am working on Ruby on Rails.
My platform is Linux.

Now I want to deploy my Ruby on Rails Application to Microsoft Azure Platform.
I am new in Azure Platform.

So How can I deploy ROR Application from Linux platform to Azure Platform.

Thanks,
Milap Shah

Comment: SSH onto the box and install the bits you need?

Comment: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/other/tutorials/ruby-on-rails/ : is this link useful for me?

Comment: Richard Astbury : can you explain me in bit detail?

Comment: Yes, that looks like a good article to follow.

Answer (score 1):

This page might contain some useful articles for you:

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/

What you'll basically need to do is this:

1. Create your Virtual Machine in the Windows Azure Portal, and select your preferred flavour of Linux.
2. SSH onto the machine, and install the various components that your applicaiton needs, i.e. Ruby, Gems, Ruby on Rails etc.. (help on this here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#installing-rails)
3. In the portal, open up the necessary endpoints in the Windows Azure firewall (i.e. port 80) to enable traffic through to your application.

Comment: Thaks Richard :) but I have question in this link https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/other/tutorials/ruby-on-rails/ ---- in this link 5) Run the following commands to install the new gems, update your Ruby Environment, and setup Capify for your project:

Comment: in this 5th section act install gems? means install capify . gem?

Comment: I think you need to ask a new question with the 'ruby' tag.

Comment: hello again .. act I have mysql as a database in my Ruby on Rails Application. so can it be possible to deploy on Azure?

Comment: Yes, you can either use the MySQL Service by ClearDB: https://www.cleardb.com/store/azure or you could migrate the database to Windows Azure SQL Database using SSMA: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/archive/2011/02/07/mysql-to-sql-server-migration-how-to-use-ssma.aspx

Comment: ...or you could just run MySQL on your Virtual Machine.